# Python regex to separate strings which ends with numbers in parenthesis

Tags: python, regex, split, strip

I have a list which is generated after a beautifulsoup operation. It has strings separated by numbers in parenthesis which I want to split as internal list. For example I have

```
L1=['alpha(1) beta(4)','delta(5) gamma(6)']
```

This needs to be converted to

```
[[‘alpha’, ‘beta’],[‘gamma’, ‘delta’]]
```

I started with this

```
[re.split(r'\(\d\)',item) for item in L1]
```

but this creates additional space in last item and then generates one more whitespace item at the end.

```
[['alpha', ' beta', ''], ['delta', ' gamma', '']]
```

So I add one more line to the code like this

```
L1=[re.split(r'\(\d\)',item) for item in L1]
[[x.strip() for x in y if x] for y in L1]
```

and this gives what I want

```
[['alpha', 'beta'], ['delta', 'gamma']]
```

So my queries are

1. Why it does what it does by using only first line of the command. Why that last element is created.
2. Is there a better way of achieving this by single and simpler regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs, `re.split()` behaves identically to `str.split()`, and the docs for `str.split()` explicitly state

> Splitting an empty string with a specified separator returns [''].

Since there's an empty string on the right side of your separator, you're getting an empty string in your `split()` result. I think the idea that returning `''` for an emtpy string results in more consistent and predictable behavior.

In regards to a better way of implementing your code, I think the following is a bit clearer:

```
>>> L1=['alpha(1) beta(4)','delta(5) gamma(6)']
>>> name_list = []
>>> for s in L1:
    name_list.append(re.findall(r'(\w+)\(\d+\)', s))
>>> name_list
[['alpha', 'beta'], ['delta', 'gamma']]
```

or using list comprehension:

```
name_list = [re.findall(r'(\w+)\(\d+\)', s) for s in L1]
```

Comment: was just coming to suggest this - `findall` is I think the more readable way of implementing what you are after.

Comment: Your explanation is very helpful and so is findall approach you suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would use split:

```
print([[j.split("(")[0] for j in  i.split()] for i in L1])
```

Returns:

```
[['alpha', 'beta'], ['delta', 'gamma']]
```

Comment: This looks very elegant way without even using regex. Thanks for that

Comment: Glad to help! In case this is the right solution for you, please mark the answer as the correct solution! Thanks

Comment: Thanks. I think the one below answers my query as well and gives me an alternative approach. I have accepted that.  Although in this case all 4 solutions posted have helped me learn a new command!

Answer (score 2):

The `\(\d\)` pattern finds multiple non-overlapping matches in your string and splits the string at those locations. That means it splits `'alpha(1) beta(4)'` into `alpha`,  `beta` and an empty string since the last `(4)` stands between  `beta` and the end of string.

If you want to use a regex with the original `re.split` approach, you may consider using `filter` to get rid of empty items in the resulting list:

```
import re
L1=['alpha(1) beta(4)','delta(5) gamma(6)']
res = [filter(None, re.split(r'\(\d+\)\s*', item)) for item in L1]
print(res)
# => [['alpha', 'beta'], ['delta', 'gamma']]
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ereCx7). The `\(\d+\)\s*` will match digits inside parentheses and `\s*` will match 0+ whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

Split on comma's and then use a regex to replace the brackets and digits. Finally split the string on spaces.

```
import re
>>> [re.sub('\(\d\)', '', y).split() for x in L1 for y in x.split(',')]
[['alpha', 'beta'], ['delta', 'gamma']]
```